# Combine 'Bar' and 'Column' chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

When I try to combine bar and column chart, it does not produce the expected chart. I have all negative values in bar and positive in column. 
The expected chart is, bar should be on negative side, and column chart should be on positive values. 
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dilani_di/yhtwaga8/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
title: {
    text: 'Combination chart'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
},
labels: {
    items: [{
        html: 'Total fruit consumption',
        style: {
            left: '50px',
            top: '18px',
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
        }
    }]
},
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
}, {
    type: 'bar',
    name: 'Average',
    data: [-3, -2.67, -3, -6.33, -3.33]
}]});
```

I want to combine the charts on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dilani_di/qufkxkn9/2/)

Comment: I don't understand from your description how you want the chart to look. For me your fiddle matches your description. Could you provide an example how you want it to look?

Comment: I don't see any combination example showing a vertical and a horizontal  `yAxis` so maybe it's impossible with highcharts.

Comment: Is this question similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459523/highcharts-combine-chart-types?noredirect=1#comment83914604_48459523 ? Note: "bar" series is the same as "column", but inverted. Screenshot of the desired result would help a lot :)

Comment: @ewolden, I have updated the question with another fiddle